# Is hybridation of design pattern a bad pratice?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, model-view-controller

My experience and understanding of design patterns comes from working with Laravel, so i'm actually only experienced in MVC design pattern, but I found my self developing a sort of "autocompiling" view for each of the CRUD operations, so for example i usually put some sort of Array in my model to describe how i want the view to be generated for the model itself, and after that i write a general view that read out the model proprieties and based on the array it will generate the fields as required, something like:

```
class User extends Model{
    public $editFormArray=array(["name","text",20],
                                ["surname","text",30]);
    [...]
}
```

and the view will have and implementation that loads the model sent to it, and based on the $editFormArray propriety, it will generate itself

Something like:

```
@foreach($resource->editFormArrayas $currForm)
    @if ($currForm[1]=="text")
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-md-12">
              <input name="{{$currForm[0]}}" type="{{$currForm[1]}}"
                     placeholder="{{$currForm[0]}}" size="{{$currForm[2]}}">
           </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    [...]
@endforeach
```

this kind of approach let's me create only 1 view for CRUD operation (and some others view that can't be automatically computed, as per required) and also allows me to change the model form on the fly, adding, removing and editing fields as i see fit on the fly, but also makes my model files be really loaded.

One of my co-worker recently took a course about design patterns and thinks this is bad pratice, saying a normal MVC, with a View manually generated for each single model CRUD operation would be the right way to do it, but i think he is wrong, because the View itself doesn't really compute any real logic (all the logic is actually kept on the controller), it only computes "display logic" as in the logic required to correctly display the UX itself.

Someone could shred some light on the arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Its not bad practice to hybridize design patterns. However you have to consider some basic principles.

- How many files am I going to have to edit to modify this template? Am I editing the same files that control data storage/retrieval and business logic?
- Does someone just looking at the template have any idea what the semantic meaning of "$currForm[0]" is when they look at it? Whats the next guy that comes down the pipe who has to edit this stuff have to go on?

You're basically just making an argument that defining more things in your model makes it faster to iterate. Maybe if you team consists of one person, and they can keep the system in their head, that *could* be true, but its not true as a team or project scales up.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477771/128581

> In "Frequently Forgotten Fundamental Facts about Software Engineering"
>   by Robert L. Glass, (an article in IEEE Software May/June 2001), He
>   talks about softwares "60/60" rule, that is that maintenance typically
>   consumes 40 to 80% (60% average) of software costs, and then that
>   enhancement is responsible for roughly 60% of software maintenance
>   costs, while error correction is about 17%.

If sometimes up to 80% of the cost of software is maintenance, try to make it easy to maintain. Separation of concerns, when properly utilized, can help. Don't listen to straight dogma, but you have to think carefully about how easy something is to understand for other people and how it can help you avoid common software bugs.

Comment: Basically with good documentation of the developing process, explicative comments here and there, while also changing the "auto-design logic" variable names in a way that are easier to understand this could be actually a good way to go, right?
I mean i do it this way because the softwer design is ever-changing, so instead of writing, deleting and editing the same things hundreds of time with this approch i simply modify an array, adding/editing/deleting a single element to get the result shown in the presentation layer, so in my intention this speed up maintenance.

Comment: Yeah, you are missing the point, but hey, if your boss lets you do that, go for it.

Comment: well the thing is I am the boss in this case, and i'm trying to improve my decision making on this matter, so I would love it if you could help me hit the point, I want to understand it.